# Resizing and offsetting a range issue - runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am defining my ranges for later use in some code but keep hitting a Run-time error '1004': Application defined or object defined error.

I have established it is an issue with the resize element but cannot work out what the issue is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert

Dim ColumnArrayB As Range
    Set ColumnArrayB = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

Dim ColumnArrayA As Range
    Set ColumnArrayA = ColumnArrayB.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=-1)

Dim ColumnArrayAAdjusted As Range
    Set ColumnArrayAAdjusted = ColumnArrayA.Resize(-1, 0).Offset(0, -1).Select
```

Comment: Try erasing '.Select' from last row of your code.

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately it has not solved the issue

Comment: You cannot resize by a negative amount.

Comment: Also you are trying in the last step to go one column to the left of A...

Comment: Thanks for the advice all. Bit of a noob but looking to improve!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the above code - particularly with the line:

`Set ColumnArrayAAdjusted = ColumnArrayA.Resize(-1, 0).Offset(0, -1).Select`

1. Ending in `.select` is problematic when setting a variable.
2. Resize requires values greater than or equal 1.
3. Depending on the position of the columns, the offset does not work because you are attempting to reach a column to the left of **Column A**.

Maybe clarifying what it is you want to achieve would be helpful?

Hope this was helpful!